# Formula for constructing $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers

I want to construct $\mathbb{Z}_n$ especially for $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and the ring of integers modulo n,6. what's the explicit formula for each term in this quotient set?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you just wanting to know what the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are? If so, you should have a definition in whatever book you are reading that says what a quotient group looks like.

Comment: I don't have a book. Yes, What are the elements of know what the elements of ℤ/nℤ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Bbb Z$ is the integers, then $\Bbb Z_n=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is the set of cosets of the subgroup $n\Bbb Z$, i.e. the sets $[m]=m+n\Bbb Z=\{m+nk:k\in\Bbb Z\}$ for varying $m$. So explicitly, it is the collection of sets

$$0+n\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-2n,-n,0,n,2n,\dots\},$$
$$1+n\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-2n+1,-n+1,1,n+1,2n+1,\dots\},\\
\vdots$$
$$(n-1)+n\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-n-1,-1,n-1,2n-1,3n-1,\dots\}$$

under coset addition. You can play around with these sets and convince yourself that the addition really is what you think of as "modulo $n$", so for instance, we really have

$$((n-1)+n\Bbb Z)+(2+n\Bbb Z)=1+n\Bbb Z$$

where $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$. I'd recommend first doing this with your $n=6$, or possibly something even smaller like $n=3$ since the sets are easier to work with.

Comment: We want $0$ + $6$ $\mathbb{Z}$, $1$+$6$ $\mathbb{Z}$,... $5$ + $6$                         $\mathbb{Z}$ for $\mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: @user459897 Yes that's correct. So for instance, $1+6\mathbb Z=\{-\dots,-11,-5,1,7,13,\dots\}$. You can also check that if you try to take $7+6\mathbb Z$, then you'll get the same exact set since $1$ and $7$ are congruent modulo $6$. So it really is true that we just need the sets $m+n\Bbb Z$ for $m=0,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: +1 for a clear answer the OP seems to understand. But I hope s/he doesn't plan to use the official formal definition when actually trying to compute. A set of coset representatives is much easier!

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks, and good point. OP, assuming you see this, what Ethan is alluding to is that although I didn't state it precisely, you'll probably quickly find that $(m+n\Bbb Z)+(k+n\Bbb Z)=(m+k)+n\Bbb Z$ for all integers $m,k$. This is why we tend to instead write $[m]$ for the set $m+n\Bbb Z$, and write our well-defined "addition law" as $[m]+[k]=[m+k]$.

Comment: Can we relate everything to lagrange's theorem from group theory now that cosets are brought up?

Comment: @user459897 It's true that cosets are important in the proof of Lagrange's theorem, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "relating this to Lagrange's theorem". The theorem says that if $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$. Since we are talking about cosets of $\Bbb Z$, which is infinite, it doesn't seem that relevant. Although you could note that since $\Bbb Z_n$ has $n$ elements, any subgroup of $\Bbb Z_n$ must have order dividing $n$. I think that's about as useful it'd be in this situation, though